# PTVS or something similar in visual studio 2012 express -desktop

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012, ptvs

Hey I have  visual studio 2012 express for desktop and I tried installing PTVS 2.0 and it just said it couldn't find visual studio 11, My needs arent that high but I just wanna use Vs as an IDE for Python, how do you install it?

Answer (score 6):

VS Express editions don't allow plug-ins to be installed (such as PTVS).  However, you can create your own Python Express by:

- Install the integrated Shell + Isolated Shell
- Install PTVS

Details: https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PTVS%20Installation

Comment: I  haven't been able to test it, but this mean I can get a VS IDE + PTVS even though I don't have any VS installed whatsoever (Pro or Express) ? Currently I am using VS 2012 Pro + PTVS, and would like to find out whether I am able to use PTVS without a VS Pro. ( I still got to download IE 10 to be able to test it)

Answer (score 2):

Python Tools for Visual studio recently made available a 1-click installation.  This is based on the Visual Studio 2013 Preview bits.

The download is available: [PythonToolsIntegrated](https://pytools.codeplex.com/downloads/get/697389)